# google-bigquery Does Bigquery support single DML(insert, update, delete) SQ statement rollback?

Tags: google-bigquery

Does Bigquery support single DML(insert, update, delete) SQL statement rollback?

In other words, is there an option to make a single DML statement be an auto-commit transaction that supports rollback when it fails?

Thank you for your kind reply in advance.
Steve.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature in BigQuery that supports roll-back when a multi-statement transactions. Take a look at the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/transactions). It isn't in GA yet.

> BigQuery supports multi-statement transactions inside scripts. A multi-statement transaction lets you perform mutating operations, such as inserting or deleting rows, on one or more tables, and either commit or roll back the changes atomically.

> Uses for multi-statement transactions include:
>
> - Performing DML mutations on multiple tables as a single transaction. The tables can span multiple datasets or projects.
> - Performing mutations on a single table in several stages, based on intermediate computations.

> Transactions guarantee ACID properties and support snapshot isolation. During a transaction, all reads return a consistent snapshot of the tables referenced in the transaction. If a statement in a transaction modifies a table, the changes are visible to subsequent statements within the same transaction.

In the case of only one DML statement, BigQuery is also ACID complaint. That is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/bigquery-data-warehouse).

If an update fails, you won't have X amount of rows updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my question is about a single DML statement (not multi-statement transaction).  I am thinking it support based on this document page: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language

Comment: Hi Alvaro, 1. Does single SQL statement transaction depend on storage type? In other words, transaction is supported for all the storage types like Cloud Storage or Google Drive or Bigtable or Cloud SQL? Do they support transactions for tables on  Cloud Storage (which is my case)? 2. Do they support transactions for DDL statements (CREATE, DROP, ALTER) in BigQuery regardless of storage engine type? Thank you for your kind answer in advance.

Comment: I don't fully understand your doubts. When you are working with Drive, BigTable, GCS, etc, you are modifying the data there. You are using those as external sources. When you try to write data in an external source, you will get this error message: ".....is not allowed for this operation because it is currently a EXTERNAL"

Comment: Sorry for not being clear to you. 1. When I said I am using Cloud Storage, I just thought that BigQuery is using it as one of internal storages (storage engines). But this does not seem to be correct.I thought of MySQL storage type model like query engine with multiple storage engines with common interface.